# Fetched API Data not recognized after handling the promise with a Middleware

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, api, redux

I have been building a React-Redux application to display some weather data (openweathermap.org API) if a button gets clicked.
Somehow when the Container is rendered the data are not arriving, even if I managed to handle the promise using Axios.
 
As you can see in the console.log, the 'tempo' object is empty once it arrives in the container. Then, once the button is clicked, the request correctly arrives on the container and 'tempo' gets the data I want to render.
The problem occurs when I try to access those properties arrived after that the onClick() event was fired. They do not exist yet, so the whole components throw an error.
I think there is some problem with the async await response managed in the Axios request but I cannot find it.
Sorry if the explanation was not properly technical. 
I remain at disposal for clarifications.

Action Creator with the API request

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const GET_CECCIOLA = 'GET_CECCIOLA';


export function submitWeather() {
    const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=ce6111c5cb481755173214d6bf62f51a&q=Cecciola,it';
    const cecciola = axios.get(url);

        return {
            type: 'GET_CECCIOLA',
            payload: cecciola
        }
    }
```

Container responsible for the rendering when button is clicked

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class CecciolaTime extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.tempo)


        return (

            <div>
               <h2>{this.props.tempo}                
               </h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}


function mapStateToProps ({ tempo }) {
    return { tempo };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CecciolaTime);
```

Container with the onClick() method

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {submitWeather } from '../actions/index';



class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)


    this.getWeather = this.getWeather.bind(this);

    }


    getWeather(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.submitWeather(e);
    }





    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <button onClick={this.getWeather}>
                tempo a Cecciola
                </button>
            </form>
        )
    }
} 




function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ submitWeather }, dispatch);

}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Reducer

```
import { GET_CECCIOLA } from '../actions/index';


export default function(state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) {    
    case GET_CECCIOLA:
        return [action.payload.data, ...state];    
    }
    return state;
}
```

Reducer_Index

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import CecciolaReducer from './cecciola_reducer';

export default combineReducers({
    tempo: CecciolaReducer
  })
```

Store (I am using Redux-Promise as middleware)

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

const storeWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

render(
    <Provider store={storeWithMiddleware(rootReducer)}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
```

Comment: in the "Action Creator with the API request" use async await  or promise + read then use redux thunk dispatch

Comment: basically importing Thunk should I just wrap my submitWeather() function into the dispatch() method? Or should I just 'return dispatch {...object...}'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display non-existing property in `tempo` object and it fails - the most common way to handle it - just check if this property exists, like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class CecciolaTime extends Component {

    render() {
        const { name } = this.props.tempo

        return (
            <div>
               {/* Check if name exists then display */}
               <h2>{name && name}</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }

}


function mapStateToProps ({ tempo }) {
    return { tempo };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CecciolaTime);
```

**NOTE**: You're trying to render an object `{ this.props.tempo }` in `h2` tag, which can cause another error.

**UPDATE** (from comments): I've find the issue, it was because you're setting result into array and it's actually keeped in 0 index in array. So you can access to your variables via `this.props.tempo[0].name`. To avoid this mess just use object instead of array as initial state, it's much easier to handle then.

I've created sandbox for you with working [code (click to see)](https://codesandbox.io/s/7yz6k6412q).

Hope it will helps.

Comment: it just appear a white spot like nothing is in there...I guess it does not exist :)

Comment: @Enrico can you show what's printed out here ? console.log(this.props.tempo). Remove this in render method and just show what's printed in container.

Comment: I would like, but when I try to render {this.props.tempo} it throws an error stating React child cannot be objects, and this object has many properties of the weather conditions, such as temperature, weather etc. But then, when I tri to render, e.g. {this.props.tempo.clouds} it say that the property clouds is undefined. that happens because it is called BEFORE the promise it's resolved,I guess.

Comment: @Enrico yes, I've described you this in my answer :) So you have to check if property exists like this: `this.props.tempo.name ? this.props.tempo.name : null` or `this.props.tempo.name && this.props.tempo.name`.

Comment: ok, and if nothing renders I guess it does not exist, does it? On the screen nothing appears but no errors are thrown so I guess it does not :).

Comment: @Enrico I've updated the answer in **UPDATE** section. Please, take a look.

Comment: it works :D! so, the promise was actually handled correctly. I mean, it was not a problem of asynchronous response, it was a problem of storing the state in the correct way into the reducer?

Comment: @Enrico yes, it was a problem with getting data from your reducer. You just pushed big object (response) as first element into your state. Storing data in array isn't an error, nevertheless, in your case better to use object instead.